# Error HH210: Redefinition of task verify failed. Unsupported operation adding positional param definitions in an overridden task

Tags: hardhat-deploy

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")

const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  etherscan: { ETHERSCAN_API_KEY },
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 5,
    },
  },
}
```

deploy.js

```
const { ethers, run } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
  const VotingSystemFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("VotingSystem")
  console.log("Deployingggggggggggg")
  const votingsystem = await VotingSystemFactory.deploy()
  await votingsystem.deployed()
  console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${votingsystem.address}`)
}

async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
  console.log("Verifyingg.......")

  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      addres: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    if ((e, message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified"))) {
      console.log("Already Verified")
    } else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

Comment: We need the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem with ***hardhat-verify***. Switch to ***hardhat-toolbox*** solved the problem. Since you already has

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
```

you should remove

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
```

Source: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle

Answer (score 1):

**1. comment all**

```
   require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
    
    require("dotenv").config()
    
    require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify")
    
    require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
```

**2. Now un-comment one by one and check it by running command.
Its working for my...**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in my case i had @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan and @nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify packages (@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan has 'verify' task built in)